# Android/iOS mobile browser - disable events

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, browser, dom-events

How can I disable default mobile browser events like zoom (dblclick, expand) and options (when you hold down your finger on a screen a popup appears with options)?

I tried this:

```
document.addEventListener('ontouchstart', function(event) 
{
event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the finger move(scroll the page) like this:

```
document.addEventListener('ontouchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And the zoom you just need to adjust the `viewport` like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: hum... browser still allows two-finger zooming (dblclick is disabled).

Comment: Had you added the `<meta>` for the `viewport` at the `<head>` of your source?

Comment: Nope, I have a Motorola Milestone(Development phone) and a Samsung Galaxy S(dev & daily phone)

Answer (score 0):

If you set user-scalable=no, then minimum-scale and maximum-scale are ignored. So if you want to disable zoom, you should use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```